# Interface, Generics, c#

Tags: c#, generics, interface

My knowledge of c# is minimal.

What is the right way of doing the following?

The goal is to create an interface with a `getvalue()` that can work across a variety of structs.

```
public interface IBOB 
{ 
    T GetValue<T>() where T:struct
}

class YAY:IBOB
{
    public bool GetValue<bool>()
    {
      return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: We need more information.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect what you mean would be:

```
public interface IBOB<T> where T:struct
{ 
    T GetValue(); 
}
```

then `YAY:IBOB<bool>` and whatever other types it supports:

```
class YAY : IBOB<bool>
{
    public bool GetValue()
    {
        return true;
    }    
}
```

Note that due to naming / resolution, you may need to use explicit interface implementation for multiple types:

```
class YAY : IBOB<bool>, IBOB<int>
{
    bool IBOB<bool>.GetValue() => true;
    int IBOB<int>.GetValue() => 42;
}
```

If `YAY:IBOB` (your original), then you would need the method to be generic:

```
public bool GetValue<T>() {...}
```

otherwise it *doesn't match the signature*.